# Django no such table after migrations

Tags: django, django-models

After trying all sort of migration im still getting this error
I only get this error when trying to save the new object

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1332, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: desporto_noticia
```

Models

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone



class Noticia(models.Model):
    noticia_texto = models.TextField()
    noticia_imagem_path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    noticia_titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Default')
    pub_data = models.DateTimeField('data de publicacao')
    noticia_tema = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.noticia_texto

class Comentario(models.Model):
    noticia = models.ForeignKey(Noticia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comentario_texto = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comentario_texto
```

Went on my database software to find this is the only table non-existence, the other model has a table tables
Tried all migrates ex :

```
python manage.py makemigrations desporto
python manage.py sqlmigrate desporto 0001
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Comment: Can you share the result of your `makemigrations` and your `migrate`, please?

Comment: `manage.py makemigrations`  `Migrations for 'desporto': desporto\migrations\0001_initial.py - Create model Noticia - Create model Questao - Create model Opcao - Create model Comentario`   `manage.py migrate`  `Operations to perform: Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, desporto, sessions, sites Running migrations: No migrations to apply.`   (Added more models, all have tables except "noticia") @HuLuViCa

Answer (score 0):

Your migrations for the Noticia model has been recorded in the Django migrations table but deleted from the database. If it is not in production you can drop the database and rerun the migrations with the fresh database schema. If you don't want to drop the database then you can delete the migration entry from the migrations table and rerun the migrate command.

**Notice**: Please don't experiment it with the production database.